# Saving frayed cables?

Tags: cable, frugal, vintage

I've got a '70s road bike with shift cables which work quite well and so I see no immediate reason to replace them, but the cable ends were not crimped with end caps and so they've frayed out to ridiculous levels. However, I can't just cut off the frayed end and re-crimp it because then my cables would be too short; Is there any way for me to "save" these cables and avoid having to re-cable the bike? Is there no way to "de-fray" the ends even if it doesn't leave them in "pre-frayed" condition?

Comment: New wires are quite cheap, so it might be easier to just buy new ones. You can still use the old housing.

Comment: you can tape them and solder the end

Comment: You can also re-wind the strands and use crazy glue so they don unwind again.